# Iterating through dictionary values to form URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to iterate through the values in the dictionary below in order to add each value to form a unique URL (using Python 2 here):

```
base_url = 'https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/'
magazine = {
    'La Lettre du Cancerologue': '14',
    'La Lettre du Pharmacologue': '10',
    "La Lettre de l'Hepato gastroenterologue": '4',
    "La Lettre de l'Infectiologue": '2'
    }
```

When I iterate through itervalues, it sequentially adds each number to the previous number. Code and output below:

```
for itervalue in magazine.itervalues:
    base_url = base_url + itervalue
    print base_url

https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/4
https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/410
https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/4102
https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/410214
```

Whereas the intended output is achieved when I do not save the result to a variable...

```
for itervalue in magazine.itervalues:
    base_url + itervalue

'https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/4'
'https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/10'
'https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/2'
'https://www.edimark.fr/resultat-recherche/magazine/14'
```

Could anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here? Pretty new to Python, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Look at the line `base_url = base_url + itervalue`.  It is _accumulating_ within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
for itervalue in magazine.itervalues:
    aux_base_url = aux_base_url + itervalue
    print aux_base_url
```

you are changing the value for  `base_url` on each iteration adding to the original `base_url` all the values from `magazine.itervalues`, to fix this you could store the intermediary result in an auxiliary variable `aux_base_url`

the auxiliary variable makes sense if you want to do more then just to print if you want only to print is more convenient to use:

```
print base_url + itervalue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     base_url = base_url + itervalue
```

This is cumulative. You have to assign the new URL to another variable, for example:

```
      url = base_url + itervalue
```